# Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

[image: screenshot]

What might be causing this error in `verify_authorized` method and how to fix it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Pundit adds a method to your controller called `verify_authorized` that ensures that the `authorize` method is called somewhere in your controller action.  You likely setup an `after_action` that calls `verify_authorized` (https://github.com/elabs/pundit#ensuring-policies-and-scopes-are-used).  Make sure you're calling `authorize` in each possible execution path through your controller action.

Alternatively, if you do not want to authorize that particular action, you can skip it:

```
class PagesControler < ApplicationController
  include Pundit
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: [:home]

  ...
end
```

or if you setup the `after_action` in an inherited controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  after_action :verify_authorized

  ...
end

class PagesControler < ApplicationController
  skip_after_action :verify_authorized, only: [:home]

  ...
end
```