# Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError in PagesController#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a website where a user can see multiple poetries or write his own.
I am using Devise and Pundit for authentication and authorization.

When the user goes to the main link (http://0.0.0.0:3000/), I want him to be able to see the page even if he is NOT logged in. The HOME page is simply an HTML page with a buttons that, if clicked, redirects to all the poetries (poetries controller).

However, I am experiencing the following error:

```
Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError in PagesController#home
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  after_action :verify_authorized, :except => :index, unless: :devise_controller?
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, :only => :index, unless: :devise_controller?

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  private

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = "Non sei autorizzato a eseguire questa azione"
    redirect_to(root_path)
  end

end
```

**pages_controllers.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  include Pundit

  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:home]
  # skip_after_action :verify_authorized, except: [:home]
  # after_action :verify_authorized, except: [:home]
  # before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:home,]


  def home
  end
end
```

I tried following this guide:
[Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071428/punditauthorizationnotperformederror)
But I keep getting the same error.

I did NOT create a `pages_policy.rb` but I do not think this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.
Since `PagesController` is inheriting from `ApplicationController`, and the latter contains `before_action :authenticate_user!`, I have to write the following in `PagesController`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  include Pundit
    skip_after_action :verify_authorized, only: [:home]

    skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:home]

  def home
  end
end
```